# IE: Why does preventDefault(), when called twice on a submit request result in a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I had a bug on IE with a login form that resulted on a page refresh, and I realized it was happening because I was accidentally calling event.preventDefault() twice in my code.

This does not happen with other browsers. Is there a logic explanation to get this behavior with IE?

Code (can't be recreated on a fiddle):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="myForm" method="POST">
  <label for="someInput"></label>
  <input id ="someInput" type="text">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
var myForm = document.querySelector('#myForm');
myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of IE? Can't reproduce on IE11, even in a standalone page.

Comment: IE version 11.0.10586.0